# White screen in listview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this adapter? I'm getting an empty RecyclerView but a list that has 11 items in it? we have checked the customer class and the MainActivity and it seems to be correct. we log the customers.size in the getitems and find that there should be no trouble. could it be something wrong with the viewHolder class?

```
package com.example.jenso.test1yay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;



public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private List<Customer> customers;
  private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<Customer> listItems ,Context context){
    this.customers = listItems;
    this.context = context;





}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent, false);


    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Customer customer = customers.get(position);

        if (holder != null) {
            holder.textViewHead.setText(customer.getName());
            holder.textViewDesc.setText(customer.getLastName());
        }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: "+ customers.size());





    return customers.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewHead;
    public TextView textViewDesc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
    }
}


}


package com.example.jenso.test1yay;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Customer> customers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    customers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        Customer customer = new Customer("Jens" + (i+1),
                "Svensson"
                );
        customers.add(customer);
    }

    adapter = new MyAdapter(customers, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Description"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHead" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Heading"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jenso.test1yay.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your activity class where you set the adapter

Comment: My best guess is that you've forgotten to set a LayoutManager to your RecyclerView

Comment: Can you provide your activity's xml file?

Comment: Try with removing fixed size=true on your recycler view

Comment: item layout xml file requiref :3

Comment: sorry nope removing fixed size didn't work

Comment: we asked you to post item.xml

Comment: im trying it keeps on telling me that it's formatted wrong

Comment: check if your textView textColor is white color

Comment: nope textView color is def

Answer (score 0):

Try change size of `TextView` `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `100dp`

Comment: nope sorry we have a context set from the variable context in our main

Comment: Try replace `private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;`
by `private MyAdapter adapter`

Comment: Change `android:layout_width="0dp"`
to `100dp` bro

Comment: You changed size of view  with id "@+id/cardView" ?

Comment: yea we did that but the uidesigner gives us a fully sized cardview and recycler view eaven if it had 0 dp

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but try to pass the activity's `Context` into the adapter and then use that context in `LayoutInflater.from` instead of `parent.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

i make some correction in your code try it.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<Customer> listItems, Context context) {
    this.customers = listItems;
    this.context = context;


}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);


    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Customer customer = customers.get(position);

    if (holder != null) {
        holder.textViewHead.setText(customer.getName());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(customer.getLastName());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + customers.size());


    return customers.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewHead;
    public TextView textViewDesc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
    }
}
```

}

in main activity..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private List<Customer> customers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        customers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            Customer customer = new Customer("Jens" + (i+1),
                    "Svensson"
            );
            customers.add(customer);
        }

        adapter = new MyAdapter(customers, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```